# How can I make a Rust function accept any floating type as an argument

Tags: generics, polymorphism, rust

I'm looking to write a function that can accept any floating point data, similar to the following form:

```rust
fn multiply<F: Float>(floating_point_number: F) -> F {
    floating_point_number * 2
}
```

But I can't find the syntax for it in the documentation, or a trait that is common to floating point numbers only.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Currently all of the generic story with primitive numeric types in Rust is available in the official [`num`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/index.html) crate. This crate contains, among everything else, a number of traits which are implemented for various primitive numeric types, and in particular there is [`Float`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.Float.html) which represents a floating-point number.

`Float` trait provides a lot of methods which are specific to floating-point numbers, but it also extends [`Num`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.Num.html) and [`NumCast`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.NumCast.html) traits which allow one to perform numeric operations and obtain generic types from arbitrary primitive numbers. With `Float` your code could look like this:

```
use num::{Float, NumCast};

fn multiply<F: Float>(n: F) -> F {
    n * NumCast::from(2).unwrap()
}
```

`NumCast::from()` returns `Option` because not all numeric casts make sense, but in this particular case it is guaranteed to work, hence I used `unwrap()`.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but `num` doesn't seem to be an official crate anymore, right? Also how does `num` relate to `num_traits`, is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: @bluenote10 if I recall correctly, originally `num` was extracted from the standard library, that's why I called it "official". I don't think it is really official as in "supported by Rust developers". As for the difference between `num` and `num-traits`, it is actually described in the former's readme: https://crates.io/crates/num. Basically, `num` reexports `num-traits` and also other crates in the `num-*` family, which is useful if you need many of them.